# Storing names of fonts in an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, fonts, cydia

How can I store the names of all the fonts available on iOS in an NSMutableArray? This is for later usage and for displaying them on a table view

Comment: Why does this have to be a mutable array?  It's pretty tough (or impossible?) for a user to add / subtract fonts from a iPhone.

Comment: Its for a jailbroken environment. I just wanted to add this in case apple decides to add new fonts in a minor update. This tweak is compatible with iOS 5 and 6 that is why I'm doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

all font names installed:

```
id families = [UIFont familyNames];
id fonts = [NSMutableArray array];
for(id fam in families) {
    [fonts addObjectsFromArray:[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:fam]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`[UIFont familyNames]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/familyNames) is what you are looking for. If you also want to know what kind of fonts are available in a given family, you can use [`[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/fontNamesForFamilyName%3a).

They both return an inmutable array, if you really need a mutable one (for whatever reason), you can simply make a mutable copy of it.

Comment: I'l decide whether to accept your answer after seeing the other's. But its upvote 1 for you!

Comment: those are the family names.. each family has x fonts and you call fontNamesForFamily: